# using mongoose to findOne method to check if my customListName from express route parameters already exits or not

Tags: mongoose-schema

```
List.findOne({name:customListName})
.then(function(err,foundList) {
  if (!err) {
    if (!foundList) {
      console.log("dn");
    } else {
      console.log("e");
    }
  }
```

I was expecting to have a log on my console as "exits" or "not exit" if the customListName already exits or not .

Answer (score 0):

Then what are  you getting after running the code? Also try to console log the err & foundList parameters, the code might be working.

```
if(!err) {
  if(!foundList) {
  console.log("does not exist");
  } else {
  console.log(foundList);
  }

 } else {
 console.log(err.toString());
}
```